# Obtain WAN IP address from Google Assistant Webhooks

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

During the Account Linking of our app with Google Assistant, we authenticate the user by mapping its WAN IP Address.

Once Webhooks intents are received, they are coming from Google cloud, not the user device, so the WAN IP doesn't match. It's then impossible to know if the user is still at home.

It seems there are ways of obtaining user and device identity, like name or device location. Is there a way of obtaining the device WAN IP address?
(à la x-forwarded-for).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short - no.

The Assistant platform is meant to allow users to, somewhat transparently, move from device to device. The device ID isn't even standard.

If you need to know their location to make sure they haven't moved, then you can [ask for their physical location](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#user_information). For speaker devices, such as the Home, it will use the device location that was set by the user, but for mobile devices it will use the GPS.